# Searching for punctuation in Preview

Tags: pdf, preview, search, internationalization

In Preview (v 5.3 on 10.6.8), if I search for a single letter such as `k` in a pdf, the program will find and highlight every instance of that letter in the pdf.

However, if I search for a punctuation mark such as `?` or `;`, it will report `Found on 0 pages`, even when the document is littered with such punctuation.

How can I get preview to search for punctuation?

The reason for this is that I wish to locate all instances of missing references (denoted as `[?]`) in a pdf output from `LaTeX`. 
(Yes, I know that `LaTeX` will tell me where they are in the source file, but I wish to find them in the pdf.)

Comment: Can you search for `[?]` instead?

Comment: No that doesn't work either... In fact if I search for `[?] d` it will find all locations of `d` and completely ignore the punctuation. I think punctuation is being stripped before the search. Probably nothing I can do about it.

Answer (score 4):

A year late but may help others:

For me escaping it in double bracket works so try searching `":"` or `"?"`.

Escaping in double quotes searches for whatever is between the quotes similar to the way google does their search options.

Comment: Double brackets don't seem to work for the OP's problem whatever is stated inside square brackets are taken as sets of items.

Comment: This does not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Does it have to be in Preview?  Preview doesn't seem to have this functionality as of El Capitan (10.11).  However, I have found and tested two ways that you can search PDF files for punctuation.

1. [Acrobat Reader](https://get.adobe.com/reader/)
2. `pdfgrep`

#### Acrobat Reader

Using Adobe Acrobat, I simply entered the punctuation into the search field in this case a colon (:) and Acrobat found all instances of it.

[image: Sample PDF Page]

*Note:  I did successfully test out the question mark (?) and it worked.  Unfortunately, the only document I had at the ready had personal info on it so I couldn't use it as an example.  However, I made sure to test different punctuation from periods, exclamation points, question marks, commas, etc. and all worked.*

#### `pdfgrep`

pdfgrep is the PDF equivalent to the command line (CLI) utility [`grep`](http://ss64.com/bash/grep.html).  The useage is simple:

`pdfgrep [OPTIONS] PATTERN FILE`

So, to search for a comma, and have it tell you what page number it occurs on, simply issue the command:

`pdfgrep -n "?" foobar.pdf`

`pdfgrep` is FOSS software and available on [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/).  See [`man pdfgrep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/pdfgrep.1.html) for more info.